# How to get bash not to treat [ as a test character when using command substitution?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

How can I get unmodified output from `$()` in bash?

I need to have bash return the results of command substitution (via `$(command)` or `` `command` ``), but bash treats the left square bracket as the `test` builtin and evaluates the text.

```bash
> echo "This shows an IP in brackets [127.0.0.1] when not in the command substitution context."
This shows an IP in brackets [127.0.0.1] when not in the command substitution context.

> echo $(echo "This should show an IP in brackets [127.0.0.1] but instead evaluates to '1'.")
This should show an IP in brackets 1 but instead evaluates to '1'.

> echo $(echo "The subtle addition of a space causes [127.0.0.1 ] to behave differently.")
The subtle addition of a space causes [127.0.0.1 ] to behave differently.
```

#### Background

Please note that the use of `echo` above to provide a minimal example is just that; my ultimate use will be including output from `ping` or `tracert` to show the IP of a host as seen by that host (i.e. respecting any hosts entries). In this usage, I have little control over the string being output by the command.

```
> grep -E "^[^#].*stackoverflow" /c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com

> tracert -h 1 -w 1 stackoverflow.com | awk '/Tracing/'
Tracing route to stackoverflow.com [127.0.0.1]

> ping -n 1 -w 1 stackoverflow.com | awk '/Pinging/'
Pinging stackoverflow.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:

# Using dig or nslookup would show a real IP rather than the forced IP from the hosts entry.
> dig @ns1 +nocmd stackoverflow.com +noall +answer
stackoverflow.com.      118     IN      A       151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com.      118     IN      A       151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com.      118     IN      A       151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com.      118     IN      A       151.101.65.69

> echo $(ping -n 1 -w 1 stackoverflow.com | awk '/Pinging/')
Pinging stackoverflow.com 1 with 32 bytes of data:

> echo $(ping -n 1 -w 1 stackoverflow.com | awk '/Pinging/ {print $3}')
1

> ping -n 1 -w 1 stackoverflow.com | awk '/Pinging/ {print $3}'
[127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with the `[` test operator; `[127.0.0.1]` is a shell glob that's matching a file named `1` that happens to exist in the current directory (and would also match files named `0`, `2`, `7` if such existed)

Comment: I don't entirely understand the background section, but the first three commands work as expected to me. I never see an output of `1` in `bash 4.4.23(1)`. I also agree that it's probably not the test operator, because you need a space after the `[` to use that. Finally, I'm not sure if relevant, but you can always use `printf '%s\n' $(...)`.

Comment: @steeldriver Nice catch. That was exactly the issue. I'd attempted to redirect stderr to stdout for `curl` (so I could `grep` the `--verbose` output) months ago and created the file accidentally when I'd run it with `2>1` rather than `2>&1`. If you re-post this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Having a file named `1` is the symptom; the cause is insufficient quoting.

Comment: @BQ. my observation isn't really an answer - as @JeffSchaller points out, you should fix the root cause (i.e. make sure `[...]` isn't treated as a filename glob) rather than relying on there being no files that happen to match it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the command substitution is not itself quoted. When command substitution uses the output of the `echo` command as the argument for the second `echo` command, the command results are subjected to both word splitting and file globbing. As pointed out in the comments, the characters within square brackets, `[127.0.0.1]` will match any files whose name is exactly one character and is one of either `1`, `2`, `7`, or `0` (the pattern would match `.` only the shell ignores both the `.` and `..` directory links).  When I created a file called `1` I could replicate your result.

To avoid the results of the command substitution being subjected to globbing, you should wrap it in double quotes:

```
echo "$(echo "This will show an IP address in square brackets: [127.0.0.1]")"
```

See also the following related articles from Greg‘s Wiki (particularly the first one which covers the need for double-quoting both within and outside the command substitution):

- [Command Substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)
- [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- [Globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Comment: Note that unlike what the syntax highlighting on SE seems to imply, the `"$(echo "` part is not a single quoted string. The inside of a command substitution is a separate context from the outside, and the quotes don't mix between them. Both sets of quotes are needed here, since there are two places where the globbing can happen.

Comment: Thanks @ilkkachu  The syntax highlighting was confusing, alright but I figured out how to disable it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work
I also emphasised the first related link which covers this issue.